# LDS Multiselect picklist

Tags: lightning-design-system, multi-select, svg

I am trying to use the following code from the Lightning Design System documentation.  I am getting SVG errors.  Can someone tell me how to resolve this?  Can I use something other than the svg code?
  [image: ing co]

Comment: could you add some code and context on where you are doing this? in lwc or aura components oor off platform ?

Comment: If you're developing in a Salesforce org, consider using `lightning-record-form` or any other [base lightning components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components) which handle most of the visuals/icons you'd normally want to use

Comment: I decided to use lightning:dualListbox instead of the combobox.